# wget only works with --secure-protocol option RHEL8

Tags: wget, rhel, luarocks

I am trying to call wget `'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rocks-moonscript-org/moonrocks-mirror/master/manifest-5.3'` on an AWS instance based on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.7 (Ootpa). It fails with `GnuTLS: No or insufficient priorities were set. Unable to establish SSL connection.` while it works using option`--secure-protocol TLSv1_2` or --secure-protocol TLSv1_3`.

Any ideas how to fix this so that I can call luarocks which in turn implicitly calls wget (without --secure-protocol) to download its needed package info.